# PHP 7.2 and modules 'dom', 'mbstring', and 'simplexml'

Tags: php, dom, simplexml, php-7.2, mbstring

I installed PHP 7.2 on my server and everything works fine except these three issues:

I face these problems:

> The PHP extension `dom` is not loaded. Please contact your server
>   administrator or visit http://php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php
>   for installation.
>
> PHP extension mbstring is not loaded. Please contact your server
>   administrator or visit
>   http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php for installation.
>
> PHP extension simplexml is not loaded. Please contact your server
>   administrator or visit
>   http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php for installation.

...

Now when I type `php -m`,

```
[root@localhost php.d]# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
zlib

[Zend Modules]

[root@localhost php.d]#
```

It shows that there isn't any `mbstring`, `dom` or `simplexml` modules.

I've tried everything that I can find on google, but I can't seem to install those three modules.

`php -v` returns this:

```
PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 20 2018 08:21:26) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

What's wrong?

Comment: by the way, its just an ordinary LAMP stack

Comment: The nice little prank here is that the [PHP docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php) (for `simplexml` and `dom`) that "This extension is enabled by default.", but, apparently, some distributions (like also Debian, here) have chosen to disagree, just for the fun of it. (Well, I suspect it's just a matter of progress: perhaps the xml package was just not yet debianized when 7.2 debuted.)

Answer (score 9):

Try installing the missing modules as:

```
sudo yum install php7.2-dom

sudo yum install php7.2-mbstring

sudo yum install php7.2-simplexml
```

Don't forget to restart server after installation.

Comment: Lovepreet thanks for the reply. Im using Centos. I type yum search mbstring and this is the result... php72-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
php72u-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling. I dont know which one to use

Comment: for ubuntu try this `sudo apt-get install -y php-simplexml`

Answer (score 1):

This may be weird, but once you install these (below commands) depending on your version (mine is 7.3 at the time of post), the modules get enabled somehow.

```
apt-get install php7.3
apt-get install php7.3-common
apt-get install php7.3-cli

service apache2 restart

php -m
```